# Android - Dialog listener reference gets lost on configuration change

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have Fragment which also contains a DialogFragment. In order to do something when a dialog button is pressed, I am using a `DialogListener` interface: that interface implements a method `onPositiveButtonPressed` that is called by the dialog when the button is pressed. The fragment implements that interface and passes itself as a reference to the dialog when instantiating.

Here's the code:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener 

    public interface DialogListener {
        public void onPositiveButtonPressed(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    public ExerciseCreationDialog(MyDialogListener fListener) {
        listener = fListener;
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);

        builder.setView(view)
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button_label, (dialog, id) -> 
                    listener.onPositiveButtonPressed()) // here the listener comes into play
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Then in the fragment, I instantiate it like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonPressed(DiloagFragment dialog) { 
       // do something ...
    }

   public void createDialog() {
      DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialog(this);
      dialog.show();
   }
}
```

The method `createDialog` is called when a button in the fragment is clicked.

The problem with this is that, upon configuration change (e.g. rotating the screen), if I have the dialog open, the `listener` reference inside the dialog becomes null. This is probably due to either the dialog, the fragment, or both, being reinstantiated.

Is there a way I can persist this and avoid losing the reference?

Comment: *Is there a way I can persist this and avoid losing the reference?* using anti-pattern like not allowing to configuration change occure ... use callback which is implemented in parent fragment or activity

Comment: [like this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/2c8e8ba2954f1ae204190501682e8039)